# Struggling with local addons odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I'm trying to configure local addons on Odoo 11.0 but it's not working.

**In my odoo.conf file, located in /etc directory, here's what I've added:**

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
addons_path = /opt/odoo/odoo/addons,/opt/odoo/local-addons
```

In the **local-addons** directory, I've installed a third party app.
But when I run `./odoo-bin` and refresh the apps list, I still don't see my app.

**I've also noticed 2 strange things:**

**1.** When I remove the first path (`/opt/odoo/odoo/addons`), the server still loads the basic modules
 **2.** When I install a third-party app in the default directory (`/opt/odoo/odoo/addons`), everything works perfectly fine.

Please help me if you know why things aren't working out!

Answer (score 1):

By default, Odoo uses 'addons' and 'odoo/addons' directories for addons.

In your case, I think your configuration file is not used by Odoo. Can you give us the way you run Odoo ?

You should use : ./odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo.cfg